# Получение снимка максимального разрешения с ip камеры

Tags: flutter, dart, onvif

С Ip камеры получаю ссылку http://[ip-address]:[port]/snapshot.cgi на запрос c GetSnapshotUri. Но после прослушивания http сниффером разных приложений которые получают снимок максимального разрешения с этой камеры, понимаю что запрос GetSnapshotUri он просто для инициализации камеры, а когда непосредственно нажимаем на кнопку "сделать снимок", никаких запросов не отправляется, хотя слушаются вроде разные протоколы программкой HttpCanary на Андроид
По ссылке с ip адресом снимок с профиля небольшого разрешения.

На [с++ делают так](https://www.genivia.com/examples/onvif/index.html#ONVIF_Client_Application_in_C++_to_Retrieve_Image_Snapshots):

```html
  // for each profile get snapshot
  for (int i = 0; i < GetProfilesResponse.Profiles.size(); ++i)
  {
    // get snapshot URI for profile
    _trt__GetSnapshotUri GetSnapshotUri;
    _trt__GetSnapshotUriResponse GetSnapshotUriResponse;
    GetSnapshotUri.ProfileToken = GetProfilesResponse.Profiles[i]->token;
    set_credentials(soap);
    if (proxyMedia.GetSnapshotUri(&GetSnapshotUri, GetSnapshotUriResponse))
      report_error(soap);
    check_response(soap);
    std::cout << "Profile name: " << GetProfilesResponse.Profiles[i]->Name << std::endl;
    if (GetSnapshotUriResponse.MediaUri)
      save_snapshot(i, GetSnapshotUriResponse.MediaUri->Uri.c_str());
  }
```

Мне нужно на Flutter (dart)

Comment: Пожалуйста не создавайте много одинаковых вопросов. Если вопросы смежные их необходимо объединить.